# Cannot access virtualhost via servername but can with alias

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I can access site perfectly via alias, but not servername:

```
<virtualhost *:80>

      ServerAdmin xx@gmail.com
      ServerName xx.com
      ServerAlias www.xx.com

      #DirectoryIndex index.html
      DocumentRoot /var/www/xxx

      #Allow .htaccess files to work
      <Directory /var/www/xxx>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
      </Directory>

      #Custom log file locations
      LogLevel warn
      ErrorLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/x_er.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/x_ac.log combined

</virtualhost>
```

How is it possible? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you give us more information about how it's failing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the name `xx.com` isn't resolvable in DNS.  What does `host xx.com` say?  If it says "Host xx.com not found", then that's the trouble and you'll need to give that name an alias or IP address in your domain's DNS.

Comment: It is resolvable, it shows me 000-default config. I did a2dissite 000-default and it works as expected. So why is 000-default interfering?

Comment: If you suspect the problem to related to 000-default, please include that config in your question

Comment: run apache2ctl -S It will tell you what hosts the server thinks exist, and where.